# How to customize excel auto filter popup screen using VSTO com add-ins in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

I am creating a com add-in using VSTO C# but couldn't find a function or event that allows to **sort tree nodes** manually and **add a toggle button** in excel auto filter popup screen from code. Here is the sample image attached as I want.

[image]

Comment: There's no VSTO or automation interface to do this.

Comment: Can we achieve this functionality from code behind? If not then I guess user control is the only solution. In that case we need to re-implement  complete functionality for custom auto filter control.